# Not able to login when comparing hashed password from MYSQL database using nodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, session

> Below is the code snippet of a system which is asking email and password to Login into the system. The below code is always showing error that "email or password is incorrect" even if they are correct. I am using NodeJS and MySQL database, Please help!

```
exports.afterLogin = async (req, res) => {
try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    db.query('Select * FROM patient WHERE email= ?', [email], async (error, results) => {
        const verified = bcrypt.compareSync(password,results[0].password);
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
        //console.log(results);
        else if (!results || !verified) {
            res.status(400).render('patientLogin', {
                message: 'Email or password is incorrect!',
                messageClass:'alert-warning'
            });
        }

        else {
            //creating session
            db.query('select * from patient where email=?',[email],(err,result)=>{
                if(err)
                {
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    
                    sess=req.session;
                    sess.patient={};
                    sess.patient.city=result[0].city;
                    sess.patient.name=result[0].first_name;
                    sess.patient.ids=result[0].patient_id;

                    
                   // console.log(sess.patient);
                    patientSess=Object.assign(sess.patient);
                    
                   // console.log(patientSess);
            
                }
            });

            const id = results[0].id;
            const token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
            });
            console.log("Token is: " + token);

            const cookieOptions = {
                expires: new Date(
                    Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                ),
                httpOnly: true
            }
            res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
            res.status(200).redirect("/searchDoctor");
        }
    })

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us how your hashed passwords were generated, and show us that code if possible. It's likely the passwords were hashed with something other than `bcrypt`, and you'll need to compare them the same way. Also put your `.compareSync` line *after*, not before, your error check to rule out some kind of SQL error.

Comment: You shouldn’t need to query the database twice - just use the same results. This code would be a lot easier to read if you were using async/await vs. callbacks.